# Erro System.NullReferenceException ao tentar passar Valor de um Form para outro Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Tenho na minha aplicação um Form de cadastro de clientes e um Form de busca de clientes. Para enviar valores de um form para outro utilizo o código a baixo, já utilizei esse mesmo código em vários outros forms e funciona perfeitamente, porém nesse cadastro não esta funcionando. Fiz vários testes e percebi que é porque estou utilizando um tabControl.

> Erro que ocorre: System.NullReferenceException      HResult=0x80004003
>   Message=Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um
>   objeto.

Não estou conseguindo decifrar como faço para resolver esse problema, alguma ideia?

> Estou enviando por referencia, pois por construtor não funciona com os
>   dois forms abertos.

```
 Form form1 = Application.OpenForms["FormCadastro"];
    Label LbTeste = (Label)form1.Controls["LbTeste"];
     LbTeste.Text = "SIM";
```

Comment: LbTeste está aonde? no Tabcontrol? se estiver primeiro se busca ele depois se busca o Label!

Comment: Nem sei se não vai precisar informar também qual é a aba do TabControl... Mas o caminho é esse

Comment: Sim, ele esta no tabControl.

Comment: então no form1 busque `form1.Controls["tbControl"]` e verifique se o retorno é o tbControl ai dentro do tbControl busca os componentes e assim por diante!

Comment: Não sei se entendi, seria algo assim? Form form1 = Application.OpenForms["FormCadastro"];    TabControl tabControl1 = (TabControl)form1.Controls["tbControl1"];
    Label LbTeste = (Label)form1.Controls["LbTeste"];
     LbTeste.Text = "SIM";

Comment: Isso tudo vai depender se essa é a sequencia dos componentes ... talvez seja mas, é bem isso ai .... você precisa identificar quais elementos precisa buscar até chegar no mais interno.

Comment: Virgilio Novic, segui a dica e deu certo, tive que buscar a TabControl, depois a TabPage e ai sim o Label. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Abraço

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

```
Form form1 = Application.OpenForms["FormCadastro"]; 
TabControl tabControl1 = (TabControl)form1.Controls["tbControl1"]; 
TabPage  tabPage1 = ( TabPage )tabControl1 .Controls["tabPage1 "]; 
Label LbTeste = (Label)tabPage1 .Controls["LbTeste"]; 
LbTeste.Text = "SIM";
```

É preciso informar o TabControl e a TabPage que os valores serão passados.

Answer (score 0):

Os Forms são classes como outras quaisquer, basta você criar propriedades ou tornar os controles públicos pra acessar.

O método que você usou, funciona, pois todos os controles, ficam armazenados na coleção `Controls` do Form e são acessíveis da mesma forma que um array, informando a key (no caso o nome) do controle. Mas, além de ficar um código bagunçado, experimente mudar o nome de um dos controles, nem mesmo a refatoração da IDE irá atualizar as mudanças e trará um problema terrível.

Há outras formas de fazer o que você precisa, como disse acima, você pode criar propriedades públicas e acessar de um outro objeto. Exemplo:

No Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public string PropriedadeForm1 { get; set; }

    public string LabelForm1 { get { return labelForm1.Text; } set { labelForm1.Text = value; } }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonAbrirForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show(this); //Passa a instância do Form1 (this) como Owner da instância do Form2
    }

    private void buttonSetPropriedadeForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = this.OwnedForms.OfType<Form2>().FirstOrDefault(); //Seleciona a instância do Form2 que é 'Owned' por esta instância do Form1

        if (form2 != null) //Se há um Form2
        {
            form2.PropriedadeForm2 = textBoxForm1.Text; //Define a propriedade
        }
    }
}
```

Repare nas propriedades públicas `PropriedadeForm1` e `LabelForm1`, elas serão acessíveis de fora do Form.

Repare também que, ao instânciar o Form2, foi passado `this` como parâmetro do método `Show`. Isso faz com que a instância do Form2 seja possuída por esta instância do Form1. Posteriormente, podemos acessa-las pelas propriedades `OwnedForms` do Form1, e `Owner` do Form2.

Agora um exemplo do Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string PropriedadeForm2 { get; set; }


    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonMostraLabelForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = this.Owner as Form1;
        if (form != null)
            MessageBox.Show(form.LabelForm1);
    }

    private void buttonSetLabelForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = this.Owner as Form1; //Pega a instância do Form1 que é dona desta instância do Form2

        if (form != null)
            form.LabelForm1 = textBoxForm2.Text;
    }

    private void buttonPropriedadeForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.PropriedadeForm2);
    }
}
```

> Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Também há a possibilidade de tornar os campos públicos, e acessa-los de fora do Form:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma, para acessar o labelForm1 basta:

```
private void buttonMostraLabelForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form = this.Owner as Form1;
    if (form != null)
        MessageBox.Show(form.labelForm1.Text);
}
```

Se utilizar essa forma no seu código, ao invés de:

```
TabControl tabControl1 = (TabControl)form1.Controls["tbControl1"];
```

seria:

```
form1.tbControl1;
```

ou

```
form1.LbTeste.Text = "Teste Label";
```